# How to use a regular expression in copy inside build event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I want to copy all files with the name ConnectionString. Is this possible?

```
copy /Y "$(SolutionDir)\MyProj\Configs\[ConnectionStrings]*" "$(SolutionDir)\MyProj.Daemon\Configs\
```

Comment: Please show/explain some example of how you want "regular expression" to be applied to your case. Right now simple DOS wildcard pattern (+1 to ericdc's answer) is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
 copy /Y "$(SolutionDir)\MyProj\Configs\*ConnectionStrings*" "$(SolutionDir)\MyProj.Daemon\Configs\
```

You can do wildcards on both ends, or on one end.

```
*.ext
string.*
*string*
```